# Modelling a simple ordering problem to have balanced delivery days

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, inventory

Assuming that I should buy 50 items from 25 different vendors with pre-known delivery duration between 2-7 day for each, which day of a week should I place each order so that the delivery days be even and balanced and even as much as possible?

What is the best way to model the simple problem below?

So a simple example is like this:

```
Items Vendors Delivery     order day of week 
1      v1       2 days       ?
2      v2       3 days       ?
3      v3       4 days       ?
4      v4       7 days       ?
.      .        .            . 
.      .        .            .
```

Comment: The problem is not well-defined. Can you explain in greater detail the relationship between the items, vendors, and delivery days?

Comment: @Richard, I have added a simple example, So I want to know which day of week ( Monday, Tuesday, ...Sunday) should I place each order so that they deliver in a distributed way( for example if I want to order 16 items deliveries be like: 4 on Monday, 4 Tuesday, 4 Wednesday, 5 Thursday).  The delivery duration for items are fixed.

Comment: The formatting in your question is confusing. I think you've tried to make a table, but it's come out all on one line.

Comment: Do I understand right then that you have 50 items you must order; each item is uniquely associated with a single delay in delivery time; and you must choose when you order the item to somehow balance the number of deliveries arriving on each day?

Comment: Exactly. You got it correctly.

Comment: So how do the vendors fit into the problem?

Comment: Vendors have different delivery times for their items.

Comment: But each item is sold by only one vendor, so each item has only one delivery time associated with it, so the vendors can be dropped from the problem?

Comment: This items should be ordered everyday week. The process repeats

Comment: Not necessarily. Sone vendors sell more than one items.

Comment: It seems to me that the most straightforward way to address this problem would be to formulate it as a MIP. It's possible that your problem reduces to something simpler, like the Wagner-Whitin model, but I don't think so.

Comment: @Sean: Then I think you may need to explain the question better and provide a more detailed example.

Comment: @Richard, the problem is exactly as you said; i want to know when to order to balance number of items arriving :)

Comment: @Sean: So, in your example the number of Items (leftmost) column is fixed, as are the vendors and delivery days, and you wish only to choose the Order Day Of Week to minimize some objective? It still seems as though the vendors don't add any constraint to the problem.

Comment: Yes. Vendors don’t add any constraint here. True. Just want the delivery of items be balanced.

Comment: @Sean: So why not just order the items randomly and divide them into 7 groups having roughly $n/7$ items each, then choose the order days so that the items arrive on the day corresponding to their group?